# Best type of microphone for ambiance taken from the top of a vehicle

Tags: laptop, ambiance

I take 360 videos from the top of my car while exploring forested areas.  I'm looking for a good external microphone I can mount on the roof that will hopefully capture nature sounds.  I always record at slow speeds (3 mph).  I'm also trying to cut down on the wind noise.

Can anyone tell me what type of microphone I should look at for my application?  My budget is around $250.  I do have a laptop in the vehicle that could power the mic if needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking 360 degree videos you have two choices here. You can either simply go for a binaural stereo solution which you can then pan into the b-format ambisonic space, or you can go for a full A-Format microphone to capture a full 1st order ambisonic ambient space.

You can get the Rode SF1 and then mount that inside some sort of buffered cage (rycote or Rode) which should give you some level of wind protection and will give you full ambisonic rendering of the sonic soundstage.

Binaural will be a bit of a compromise. Nothing I am suggesting will meet your budget and you will need a field recorder to go with it. The laptop will not power the microphone unless you have a suitable interface, then battery life becomes an issue. I strongly recommend investing in a field recorder. Zoom F4 or F8 would be the right way to go if you are on a budget.